# Window object as Global Variables Inside Function always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I dont know what I'm missing but if its always says undefined.

```
function report_grid() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "filter_option.php?action=filter",
    data: $('#form1').serialize(),
    async: false,
    success: function(rdata) {
        window.my_var = rdata
    }
})
}
$('#onscreen').click(function() {
    alert(my_var);
    return false;
})
```

All my searches to googles shows that this should work, any idea why its not working.

Comment: Who invokes `report_grid()` ?

Comment: Youre missing a couple semi-colons...

Comment: @zerkms thanks. i forgot to include the report grid() before alert.... what an idot am I. :)

Comment: @genpet: why do you want sync call? It will be deprecated soon and practically makes UX worse. PS: uhm, so is it an answer?! :-)))

Comment: @zerkms async was just put there coz i'm trying a lot of stuff coz I cant figure y its always undefined. Yes thats answer the question... I spent hours and hours searching.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, seems like you just forgot to invoke `report_grid()`